# create new container in theme

Tags: magento2, theme

i wanna remove footer container and create new footer but it does not work.
this is my code

```
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">image/logo.png</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>

    <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
    <container name="footer" htmlTag="div"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="_\_\Block\Account\Verify" name="verify_mobile_phone" template="_-_::account/verify_form.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar hi ...yes i do
footer was removed but new footer container does not create

Answer (score 1):

please assign another name and check it

like

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-inner">
```

Comment: referenceContainer  and in your code it is referenceBlock into first line

Comment: does not work ..

Comment: i update my code ...please check again

Comment: i updated my answer please check it

Comment: it's worked !!! ...but why !!

Comment: Hello, i don't know why you need, if you want to remove child block then you need to remove child block, no need to remove the container.